# If $A,B,C$ are exhaustive events , Then $P(C\cap (A\cup B)')$ is

Tags: probability

> If $A,B,C$ are exhaustive events satisfying $$ P((A\cup B)\cap \bar{C}) = \frac{1}{5}, P(B \cap C)-P(A\cap B \cap C) = \frac{1}{15}$$
>
> and $\displaystyle P(A\cap C) = \frac{1}{10}$. Then $\displaystyle P(C\cap (A\cup B)')$ is

$\bf{Attempt}:$ Using $$\displaystyle P(C\cap (A\cup B)') = P(C\cap (\bar{A}\cap \bar{B})) = P(C)+P(\bar{A}\cap \bar{B})-P(C\cup (\bar{A}\cap \bar{B}) )$$

Could some help me how to solve it, Thanks

Comment: Is some data missing? I don't see any way to compute $P(A \cap B)-P(A \cap B \cap C)$.

Comment: Are you sure that you made no mistakes? It would be nice if we had $P(A\cap C)=\frac1{10}$ as you could say in the deleted answer. I am afraid that like this the number of solutions is uncountable.

Comment: @drhab Sorry. I did the mistake of taking $A\cap C$ in place of $A \cap B$. Yes, It would be nice if $P(A\cap C) = \frac{1}{10}$.

Comment: @expiTTp1z0 Republish your solution!

Comment: @drhab Done. You are right. The number of solutions will be infinite. Given the condition of exhaustive events, I think the OP might have made a mistake in writing the question.

Comment: @Durgesh  Well, change $A\cap B$ into $A\cap C$ and things are settled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that this is not the correct solution to the problem. This is the solution to the modified problem where $P(A \cap C) = \frac{1}{10}$ is given instead of $P(A \cap B) = \frac{1}{10}$.

Use venn diagram and use the fact that $P(A\cup B \cup C) = P(S) = 1$ by assumption of exhaustive events. Required probability is $1-1/5-1/15-1/10$.

$P((A\cup B)\cap \bar{C}) = P(Orange) = \frac{1}{5}$

$P(B \cap C)-P(A\cap B \cap C) = P(\bar{A}\cap B \cap C) = P(Green) = \frac{1}{15}$

$P(A\cap C) = P(Red) = \frac{1}{10}$

To compute, $P(C\cap (A\cup B)') = P(Blue)$.
[image]

Comment: How did you figure out what $P(A \cap B)-P(A \cap B \cap C)$ was?